# How to get the tail of a path (or string) in vim

Tags: vim

I'm tuning my `vimrc` and I'd like to show in my airline bar the folder where I started vim (usually my project folder).

As the vim airline help says, I use `let g:airline_section_b = '%{getcwd()}'`
 but then I get a complete path while I'd like to get the last folder.

I've tried with :t but doesn't work: 
`let g:airline_section_b = '%{getcwd()}:t`. It just shows `/home/vivo/myproject:t` (while I want just `myproject`)

Comment: can you make an example, what do you have, and what do you want to get? it should have nothing to do with a plugin.

Comment: with the instruction '%{getcdw()} I have `/home/vivo/myproject` and I want only `myproject`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `fnamemodify()` -> `fnamemodify(getcwd(), ':t')`

Comment: yep, thanks :-) `let g:airline_section_b = '%{fnamemodify(getcwd(),":t")}'
`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you from the 7-year-later future !